# Linux kernel compilation error: undefined reference to `__udivdi3' & `__umoddi3'

Tags: linux, kernel

Here is the error I've got:
http://pastebin.com/VadUW6fy

```
drivers/built-in.o: In function `gem_rxmac_reset':
clkdev.c:(.text+0x212238): undefined reference to `__bad_udelay'
drivers/built-in.o: In function `divide.part.4':
clkdev.c:(.text.unlikely+0x7214): undefined reference to `__udivdi3'
clkdev.c:(.text.unlikely+0x7244): undefined reference to `__umoddi3'
```

I googled and found this patch: https://lkml.org/lkml/2008/4/7/82

```
--- a/include/linux/time.h
+++ b/include/linux/time.h
@@ -174,6 +174,10 @@ static inline void timespec_add_ns(struct timespec *a, u64 ns)
 {
        ns += a->tv_nsec;
        while(unlikely(ns >= NSEC_PER_SEC)) {
+               /* The following asm() prevents the compiler from
+                * optimising this loop into a modulo operation.  */
+               asm("" : "+r"(ns));
+
                ns -= NSEC_PER_SEC;
                a->tv_sec++;
        }
```

but failed to apply (may be due to new version of the file).

```
     patching file linux/time.h
     Hunk #1 FAILED at 174.
     1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file linux/time.h.rej
```

surprisingly, the file `time.h.rej` is not present!

Comment: [It would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the question here: not only is it far easier for us to read content here rather than other sites, but Stack Overflow is only as useful as its questions and answers -- and if your URLs ever go dead, this question is useless to others in the future. Thanks1

Comment: [That patch is just one line of asm and a comment](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blobdiff;f=include/linux/time.h;h=d32ef0ad4c0aaf8964d94abe215c5dbf4dde8aaf;hp=2091a19f1655aab8e5130256f83af4103efa9e3f;hb=38332cb98772f5ea757e6486bed7ed0381cb5f98;hpb=e48af19f56eb47a1f908ee8f16df9d246f955b21) -- have you tried just hand-typing that asm into the file in the correct location?

Comment: Sarnold, But the problem is the while loop is not present in the new file. ( while(unlikely(ns >= NSEC_PER_SEC)) )

Comment: @sarnold, The function in the time.h file `static __always_inline void timespec_add_ns(struct timespec *a, u64 ns)
    {
            a->tv_sec += __iter_div_u64_rem(a->tv_nsec + ns, NSEC_PER_SEC, &ns);
            a->tv_nsec = ns;
    }`

Comment: @sarnold, Thankyou for making those changes in my question. Will post nicely from now on.

Answer (score 1):

I should have read more closely. The patch is for `timespec_add_ns()`, and you have `gem_rxmac_reset()` and `divide.part.4` functions failing. Probably unrelated to the patch you found -- instead, probably standard 64-bit div / mod functions don't have an implementation on your target platform.

Do you have a Sun GEM or Apple GMAC NIC? If not, you can probably just disable that driver and get rid of the first error message.

For the second, you might need to implement a similar `asm` trick in the `clkdev.c` file -- when I skimmed my copy for a repeated subtraction operation I didn't spot one -- but maybe you can simply steal a newer `clkdev.c` or `clkdev.h` to fix this problem? (It's a long shot, there's only *one* entry in `git log drivers/clk/clkdev.c`.)

Comment: Yes, you are correct This is not for that function. I'm compiling for ARM. (so 32 bit - no 64). I 'll look into that kernel configuration for removing those GEM and NIC.

Comment: As for why the Sun GEM driver fails to compile, the ARM `udelay` function imposes a maximum of 2msec, the driver calls `udelay(5000)`.

Comment: Hey, I 've removed SunGEM and some other drivers long back but didnot make clean it. After `$ make clean` and running `$ make ARCH=${CLFS_ARCH} CROSS_COMPILE=${CLFS_TARGET}- zImage` compiled the kernel perfectly ! :) Thanks a lot